# Magento Shipping returning “Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time.” After add the Third Store

Tags: cart, magento-1, error, shipping-methods

My friend had `Magento` with `two-multi store` and he add the third store as the duplicate of one of his store.

Now, his third store's card keep returning following error 
`"Your order cannot be completed at this time as there is no shipping methods available for it"`

This only occurs on his newly added third store's cart.

What he should do?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you have to manually check and debug this issue as there is not much in UI for debugging these types of issues.

Have you tried turning on the Debug setting in the shipping settings ?

That will log your API requests into your `var/log/` directory.

Also if still you don't have idea about what causing issue then you can manually check for following things:

The function that handles shipping rules and values in checkout process is

```
Mage_Shipping_Model_Shipping::collectCarrierRates().
```

You could check whether it is being called at all or not, it should be called atleast once in your checkout process.

You could try debugging this core function by putting `Mage::log()` so that you could get idea which line causing issue.

Refer below link for more details:

[Debugging: Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/31216/debugging-sorry-no-quotes-are-available-for-this-order-at-this-time)